# WSO2 DAS server configuration issue - Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

I have configured DAS with API manager server using REST client, but not able to push data to DAS server. Please see error logs in DAS server. Could you please help me to understand what is wring in configuration?

```
TID: [-1234] [] [2016-05-20 18:07:05,566] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234 {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker}
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.throttle:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId org.wso2.apimgt.statistics.throttle:1.0.0 present in cache
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try redeploying the car app again. For that first do following

1. Delete the .car application from /repository/deployment/server/carbonapps
2. Delete any existing streams defs (related to APIM stats) by login to DAS management console and going to `Manage > Event > Streams`
3. Re deploy car app by putting it in /repository/deployment/server/carbonapps

If everything goes well you would see two scripts in `Manage > Batch Analytics > Scripts` section. Try to execute each script and see if there is any error.