# Wso2 quick guide for setting up apim with analytics leads to errors

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-das

So this is about the same error mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37347185/wso2-das-server-configuration-issue-dropping-wrongly-formatted-event-sent-for) but the difference is that i simply am trying to follow this [guide](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics), the Quick setup of it

My problem is that this setup has a lot of room for misunderstanding. How about these:

- last step, nr 4, it says "Start the WSO2 APIM Analytics server, and then start the API Manager server". Am i supposed to start it twice? with offset=1 second time or what?
- if i extract both in the same directory, what about files like License.txt

Anyway, the error says:

```
"Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.agent.exception.DataEndpointAuthenticationException: Cannot borrow client for ssl://localhost:7712"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

API Manager Server and APIM Analytics server are 2 different servers. You can download both from [WSO2 API Manager Product page](http://wso2.com/products/api-manager/). `Download Runtime` link is for API Manager Server, and `Download Analytics` link is for APIM Analytics server.

APIM Analytics server comes by default with a port offset of 1. Once you start both servers you shouldn't see above connectivity errors.

Files of 1 server shouldn't replace the files of the other. They should be extracted like this.

```
Parent_dir/__
            ├── wso2am-2.0.0/

            ├── wso2am-analytics-2.0.0/
```

Comment: i understand its two different servers, but wso2 quick guide [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/Configuring+APIM+Analytics) that i am refering to suggest i cant extract it to the same catalogue. i really would like to avoid configuring a separate database att this step, hence trying to follow wso2 quick guide.

Comment: what do you mean by `i cant extract it to the same catalogue`?

Comment: ok , i misunderstood catalogues should be  next to each other, not actually in the same place

Comment: By `catalogue`, if you meant a directory, yes. Let know if you resolved your issue.

Comment: i did resolve the issue and i have seen quite a few statistics in /publisher interface. although the das server halted after around 7.5 hours with nullpointer messages like

Comment: the problem resolved, das started with apim according to quick guide, i have seen quite some stats under /publisher interface. unfotunately the das server halted after around 7.5 hour with messages like        <br/><blockquote> (at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.Exchange.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$Exchange$$needToCopyObjectsBeforeShuffle(Exchange.scala:89)) </blockquote>

Comment: I think it's better to close this since your original issue is resolved, and start a new question with complete error trace.